# Error Saving file on Iot Core (Universal App)

Tags: file, win-universal-app, iot

I'm Trying to save data on txt files on my Iot Core (Windows 10),
and in the temperature, i wanna save that information in txt, like:

```
   private async void _timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        DhtReading reading = new DhtReading();
        int val = this.TotalAttempts;
        this.TotalAttempts++;

        reading = await _dht.GetReadingAsync().AsTask();

        _retryCount.Add(reading.RetryCount);
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AverageRetriesDisplay));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalAttempts));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PercentSuccess));

        if (reading.IsValid)
        {
            this.TotalSuccess++;
            this.Temperature = Convert.ToSingle(reading.Temperature);
            this.Humidity = Convert.ToSingle(reading.Humidity);
            this.LastUpdated = DateTimeOffset.Now;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SuccessRate));

            //Inserir aqui o método de gravação de arquivo.

                StreamWriter SW;
                SW = File.AppendText(@"Arquivo.txt");
                SW.WriteLine("Evento Gerado em: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Humidity + Temperature + "\n\r");
        SW.Close();
    }
}
```

That's the error showed to me, someone knows about it ?

> "CS1061   'StreamWriter' does not contain a definition for 'Close' and no extension method 'Close' accepting a first argument of type 'StreamWriter' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StreamWriter.Close() does not exist in UWP, it's only available in legacy .NET framework.

And No, you don't need to call it in your UWP project, just call Dispose() methods shall be fine. Below is the code sample you can follow,

```
        using (var SW = File.AppendText(@"Arquivo.txt"))
        {
            SW.WriteLine("Evento Gerado em: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Humidity + Temperature + "\n\r");
        }
```

The using clause will automatically call the Dispose method when out of scope.

Actually, if you look at the .NET [code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,9e38cb1c84769eba), line 231, calling Close() is equivalent of Dispose() except it's telling the CLR not to call the finalizer of the object.

I guess you'll be just fine using the snippet above in your UWP app.

By the way, if you want to save to a txt file on an external storage, you'll need to explicit declare the capability in the project manifest file, in the "Declarations" tab, add "File Type Associations", and one scheme with the extension of "txt". It applies to other file formats as well.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didn't work, i've a error:

#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };

Someone could help?
The temperature and humidity are 0 in my display, perhaps because the method error.

Comment: Is it like a Acess is denied exception?

Comment: Yeah, problably is an exception, 
i've think the txt file is saved in some folder in microSD, but i don't know where yet.

I wanna save the file to check this out.

Comment: Try changing the txt extension to jpg and declare Music Library in your project menifest.

Comment: i've sucess saving a file in my project,

But how can I save informations on this file ? I want to record humidity and temperature .

Comment: There's another thing, my code freeze about 1 seg while runs.

Comment: SW.WriteLine("Evento Gerado em: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Humidity + Temperature + "\n\r"); isn't it supposed to write humidity and temperature to the file?

Comment: @FelipeFerreiraMendes, did I answer you original question yet? If so please mark it so that it could be helpful for others. I have also updated my answer to be more specific.